# sass @ each with $ character

Tags: css, sass

Hi i have the following scss

```
$outlines: "primary", "danger";

.btn-outline {
  @each $outline in $outlines {
    &-#{$outline}:not(:hover) {
      background-color:#{$outline};
    }
  }
}
```

however i want the css to be

```
$outlines: "primary", "danger";

.btn-outline {
  @each $outline in $outlines {
    &-#{$outline}:not(:hover) {
      background-color:$#{$outline};
    }
  }
}
```

so that the css is outputted as

```
.btn-outline-primary:not(:hover) {
  background-color: $primary;
}
.btn-outline-danger:not(:hover) {
  background-color: $danger;
}
```

This does not work because of the $ character, is there a way to escape the $ character so that it just gets outputted or is there another way to do this perhaps with a map of some sort?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an associative array for this:

```
$colours: (
    'primary' : $primary,
    'danger' : $danger,
);


.btn-outline {
    @each $name, $colour in $colours {
        &-#{$name}:not(:hover) {
            background-color:$colour;
        }
    }
}
```